# How to use a variable as part of the path of a calling program

Tags: powershell

As a new PowerShell user, I am planning to call a local program whose path is not in the PATH environment variable. When calling the program the relative or full path of the program has to be given, e.g. `.\Users\xxx\Downloads\program_name\bin\prog`. However, as this path is way long and sometimes might be changed, so as a Linux Shell script programmer I would like to use a **variable** in the path, for instance `.\$prog_home\bin\prog`.

Hereby my question is **how to initialize this variable so that it can be used as I assumed beforehands?** I tried to initialized the variable in such way -

```
$prog_home="User\xxx\Downloads\program_name"
```

Unfortunately, this really can not work at all like in Linux Shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine a path. There is also a builtin `USERPROFILE` environment variable which you can use. This is how you could do it:

```
$prog_home = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'program_name'
$prog = Join-Path $prog_home '\bin\prog.exe'
& $prog #execute it
```

Comment: It looks to me as though you typed $prog where you meant $prog_home at one point.

Comment: @WalterMitty You are right. Fortunately sodawillow fixed it for me :-)

Comment: @MartinBrandl and alo sodawillow, great! After trying your code, I understood the working principle of Powershell a lot better now :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for the accept. If you wan't to persist such variables in your profile (so when you start powershell you already have `$prog` set, take a look at PowerShell profiles.